# Get Values of Selected Checkboxes in Express Data API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, input

So I have multiple input checkboxes, but I want to only get the data if I select the checkbox for my express post function

So here is 3 checkboxes I have with different values of 1000,2000, & 3000

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="1000" class="food">
   <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="2000" class="food">
   <input type="checkbox" name="item3" value="3000" class="food">
```

Now in express post function when I submit my form, I can get my data like this

```
const response = await client

    {
        other_data: 'other data from my forms'
        total_cost: parseInt(req.body.item1) + parseInt(req.body.item2) + parseInt(req.body.item3),
    
    }
```

The problem is when I submit my form, it will only calculate the total if I select all 3 input checkboxes and hence display the `total_cost of 6000`

But if I only click on one input checkbox, then submit my form it will show the value of 0 even though I clicked one input 1 with a value of 1000.

How do I add my data in express so that it will display my input checkbox value based on the input I clicked on? Because if I had 100 inputs, then manually adding them seems inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Just use the OR operator to catch any missing values and set them to zero:

```js
total_cost: parseInt(req.body.item1||'0') + parseInt(req.body.item2||'0') + parseInt(req.body.item3||'0'),
```

Comment: yeah but if I have 100 items this method isn't feasible

Comment: @makerbaker it's the same code you had in your question - are you asking for an alternate method to replace this?

Comment: that's just my starter code for example purposes, but I don't know how else to go about it if I had 100 items

Answer (score 0):

To better manage the input data on the backend, give each checkbox the same `name` attribute.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="1000" class="food">
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="2000" class="food">
<input type="checkbox" name="items" value="3000" class="food">
```

Then on the backend, you can just add up the values as such:

```js
total_cost: req.body.items?.reduce((a,b) => a+(+b), 0) || 0,
```

Comment: how does naming each checkbox affect my app in regards to each item? Because if I have a label under each item it would then say <label for="items">Food 1000</label>, then all the other items would have the exact same label? The data does return an array [1000, 2000, 3000] I just wasn't sure the difference with having same names or different names for inputs?

Comment: also one issue I noticed is if I don't click on any checkboxes, it crashes my app. Is there a way to write it `if !clicked` return 0, else run?

Comment: @makerbaker a set of checkboxes would usually have the same name, so the body parser will create an array of selected values with that name; if you give them separate names, it will treat it as individual checkbox groups - also, if you are getting an error when `items` isn't defined, just optional chain it (see updated answer)